# Replacement of table values in R?

Tags: r

The following is my codes:

```
Female=(1)
Male=(2)
R <- sapply(list(Female, Male), length)

Distribution = sample(c(Female, Male),
        size = 100,
        prob = rep(c(0.2, 0.8) / R, R),
        replace = TRUE)

summary(Distribution)

Distribution[Distribution == "1"] <- "F"
```

I would now like to replace all the 1s with "F" and 2s with "M". How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change vector's type to character first:

```
Distribution <- as.character(Distribution)
Distribution[Distribution == "1"] <- "F"
Distribution[Distribution == "2"] <- "M"
```

Comment: @Karl Thanks!! Very helpful. Served my purpose

Comment: but you did not select my answer ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends... If you want to use factors:

```
dd <- as.factor(Distribution)
levels(dd) <-  c('F', 'M')
```

Otherwise:

```
Distribution[Distribution == 1] <- "F"
Distribution[Distribution == "2"] <- "M" # now Distribution is a character vector
```

You may also use car::recode:

```
library(car)
recode(Distribution, '1="F";2="M"')
```

You can also use a named vector:

```
v <- c(F = 1, M = 2)
names(v[Distribution])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a factor variable:

```
factor(Distribution, levels=1:2, labels=c("F", "M"))
```